# Getting HTTP 400 when requesting access token

Tags: oauth2-playground

I am trying link Actions on Google with a 3rd party service (non-Google). I am using Google Oauth 2.0 Playground to check if I am getting the auth code and the access token. I successfully received the auth code but when requesting the access token I am receiving the following result from the response.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 16
Content-type: text/plain
WWW-Authenticate

I am not sure when I am doing wrong here. What does WWW-Authenticate mean?

Thanks in advance.